# How to delete an existing label with helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have an existing deployment that has the label `importance: normal` in spec/template/metadata/labels (all the pods spawned from this deployment have that label in them).

I want to be able to remove that label when a helm upgrade is performed.

I tried the following trying to use the `--set importance-{}` flag but get an error.

Command I tried:

`helm upgrade --install echo service-standard/service-standard --namespace qa --set importance-{} -f ./helm-chart/values.shared.yaml --wait --timeout 600s`

Error it returns:

`Error: failed parsing --set data: key "importance-{}" has no value`

Here is the snippet of the deployment that I am trying to remove the label from - The label is in the first spec block (not the second) right before `app: echo-selector` :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "8"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-12-14T15:24:04Z"
  generation: 9
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: echo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/inject: enabled
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: echo-selector
        importance: normal
        version: current
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: TEST
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: The `set` command is to override a value inside the values.yaml file, you need to take the labels from there and then you can change it during the helm upgrade.

Comment: What does the actual template code look like?  Can you [edit] the question to replace the `kubectl get deployment` output with the `templates/deployment.yaml` source code?  In particular, what templating constructs control whether that label is generated?